# How to add a sum of all bins to the graph using ggplot2?

Tags: r, histogram, facet

Here's the graph I'm trying to reproduce -
[image: desired graph]

As you can see, each histogram has a grey histogram behind it, which appears to be a sum of all. Here's what I did:

```
df <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/agricolamz/r_on_line_course_data/master/data.japanese.vocal.tract.length.csv")

df %>% 
  subset(select = -c(age, body.height, mean)) ->
  df.mod 

colnames(df.mod)[which(names(df.mod) == "a.vtl")] <- "a"
colnames(df.mod)[which(names(df.mod) == "o.vtl")] <- "o"
colnames(df.mod)[which(names(df.mod) == "i.vtl")] <- "i"
colnames(df.mod)[which(names(df.mod) == "e.vtl")] <- "e"
colnames(df.mod)[which(names(df.mod) == "u.vtl")] <- "u" 

df.mod %>% 
  gather(key = vowel, value = value, a:u) -> df.mod
df.mod %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, fill = vowel)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ vowel) +
  geom_histogram(bins = nclass.FD(df.mod$value), show.legend = FALSE)
```

It produces this kind of histogram -

[image: the graph I managed to achieve]

**How can I add that grey histogram of total values?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the histogram of all the data in a separate layer first. Note you can also simplify your code substantially using `rename_with`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/agricolamz/r_on_line_course_data/" %>%
  paste0("master/data.japanese.vocal.tract.length.csv") %>%
  read_csv() %>%
  subset(select = -c(age, body.height, mean)) %>% 
  rename_with(~sub('\\..*$', '', .x)) %>%
  gather(key = vowel, value = value, a:u) 

ggplot(df, aes(value)) + 
  geom_histogram(data = df[-2], bins = nclass.FD(df$value), fill = 'gray') +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = vowel), bins = nclass.FD(df$value)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ vowel) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  labs(x = 'length of the vocal tract',
       caption = 'data from [Hatano et. al 2012]')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the solution!